# printer is not automatically cutoff after the content ends in android java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, printing

i have a pdf printing section in both android java and website. in website while printing its correctly printing alignment and automatically the paper cut off after the content over, but while printing through android app print functionality, the paper is not automatically cutoff, after the content to be printed its taking too much blank spaces. how to solve this issue, its only with the app side printing.